# Importing database mysql using vagrant. No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, database, vagrant

I've got a sample database in a folder called test_db-master. I'm required to **"make sure the zip file is in the /vagrant directory of my vm"**. I believe that means that I have to save this db folder in the directory from which I run the vagrant up and ssh commands and I've done that.

I've got vagrant (virtual box on mac) and after I ssh into vagrant I'm required to run the following command:

```
    mysql -u root -p < employees.sql
```

After I run the above command, terminal gives me this message:

```
    -bash: employees.sql: No such file or directory
```

I have looked all over and can't find a solution. Apparently I'm supposed to see the employees database once I login to mysql and I don't. This is my first time delving into the world of VMs, mysql, apache etc (Working with LAMP). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you confirm where you run this command ? and the files in place in this directory - copy/paste from the time you run `vagrant up` would help (like run `vagrant up` then from VM `cd /vagrant` , `ls -l` and `mysql -u root -p < employees.sql`

Comment: @Frederic Henri: Woah! While trying to answer what you said, turns out I was missing the cd/vagrant step due to which VM couldn't track down the test_db-master folder after which I was able to see and access the test db. Serendipitous!

Answer (score 0):

It would most likely be that the full path to the SQL file is required, either specify it in the command 
`mysql -u root -p < \Path\To\File\employees.sql`

or make sure you are inside the folder containing the file when running the command.

`cd \Path\To\File\`

Answer (score -1):

1 step to the command line for vagrant

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

next step:

```
$ http{ 
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

and save changes.

Comment: Please check [answer] to be sure how to properly answer a question.