# How to Import a MySQL Database When Using Vagrant

Tags: mysql, ssh, vagrant, mysqlimport, vagrant-windows

I am having trouble importing a database using vagrant.

I have run `vagrant up` and everything works fine.  I then run `vagrant ssh`, sign-in to mysql, setup a database and user -- and again everything is working fine.

I then exit mysql (but NOT `vagrant ssh`) and run and run the following command:

```
mysql -u root -p mydatabase < "C:\Users\moshe\Websites\Projects\backup.sql"
```

And this point I get the following message:

```
-bash: C:\Users\moshe\Websites\Projects\backup.sql: No such file or directory
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

P.S.  In case it is relevant - I'm working on Windows 10.

P.S. 2:  I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309574/importing-database-mysql-using-vagrant-no-such-file-or-directory) and tried moving the backup.sql into the .vagrant folder and then running the mysql command, but it still didn't work.

**UPDATE**
*df command run in vagrant ssh*

```
vagrant@scotchbox:~$ df
Filesystem                                    1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                                      41251136  6750852  32764372  18% /
none                                                  4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                                            1019772       12   1019760   1% /dev
tmpfs                                            204992      380    204612   1% /run
none                                               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                                            1024956        0   1024956   0% /run/shm
none                                             102400        0    102400   0% /run/user
192.168.33.1:/C/Users/moshe/Websites/Projects 249478140 80929092 168549048  33% /var/www
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite sure that you don't have Windows 10 in your VM, are you? At least the error message contains `bash` which is normally a Linux shell.

So, if you have some Linux there, normally paths beginning with `C:\` doesn't work. Instead, there must be some mount point in the Linux file system which maps to your Windows file system (is shared).

Have a look at the `/vagrant` folder in your VM, it is very likely that you find your backup file in a sub folder of this directory. Try `find /vagrant -name backup.sql` to find the correct path.

However, `/vagrant` is only the default for mounted folders in VirtualBoxes. So, if it doesn't exist, try the command `mount | grep vboxsf` in your VM. The output should look similar to this:

```
vagrant on /vagrant type vboxsf (uid=1000,gid=1000,rw)
var_www on /var/www type vboxsf (uid=33,gid=33,rw)
```

One of the entries in your output (not the ones in this example) will be the one where your file is located.

Alternatively you can use the command `df` which gives you the direct relation between the host directory (e.g. `C:\...`) and the folder in the VM (e.g. `/var/www`).

In your case, it's the last line

```
192.168.33.1:/C/Users/moshe/Websites/Projects 249478140 80929092 168549048  33% /var/www
```

which shows that `C:\Users\moshe\Websites\Projects` (in Unix-like notation) maps to `/var/www`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I don't think I have Windows 10 in my VM.  I setup Vagrant using Scotch Box (in case that matters).  I don't know what you mean about a 'mount point' (I'm not very familiar with Linux).

Comment: I added some information how to find the file in the box.

Comment: Regarding your P.S. 2, I suppose the correct path to be /vagrant/.vagrant/backup.sql

Comment: I tried that command and got the following message:  `find: '/vagrant': No such file or directory`.  Note, I tried it from this location:  `C:\Users\moshe\Websites\Projects`.  I also ran `vagrant ssh` and tried the same search and got the same response.  Note, I am not really sure what you mean by the `/vagrant` folder in my VM.  By my VM, do you mean the directory where I run `vagrant up`.  And are you referring to the `.vagrant` folder (note the dot there)?

Comment: Your host machine should share some folder with vagrant. You need to copy your dump file to shared directory (yes, usually it is `/vagrant`, mapped to `C:\users\moshe\`) and to use `mysql` command for import with guest machine's path, like `mysql -u root -p mydatabase < "/vagrant/Websites/Projects/backup.sql"`

Comment: When I go to my `C:\users\moshe` folder, I see a `.vagrant

Comment: Go into `vagrant ssh` and enter `df` - there you should see which folders are mounted in the machine. Please post the output to let us see.

Comment: Then your command should be `mysql -u root -p mydatabase < /var/www/backup.sql`

Comment: The last line in the output of `df` shows that `C:\Users\moshe\Websites\Projects` on your Windows machine is mounted to the location `/var/www` on the VM in your case.

Comment: Thanks -- that did it.  Much appreciated.  If you want, you can write this up as an answer and I'll select it.   Either way, thanks again for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I've already added more information to my answer - though I use the output of the `mount` command instead of `df`, but works as well as an information source about the mounted file system.